# How can I rename a Page/Topic on GitHub wiki without renaming the file?

Tags: github, wiki, github-flavored-markdown

I want to update Topic/page titles on my GitHub wiki (which is *currently* using Markdown syntax).  When I do that using the GUI it renames the Markdown files, and breaks all of the links.

I know that I can rename the Topic files in the Git repository and push the changes, but that doesn't help the broken links.

Is there a way to avoid this, and make GitHub Wiki's behave more like other Wiki products?  I could not find an better way on GitHub documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow. As best I can determine you cannot rename a GitHub Wiki page without its markdown file also being updated to the new name. The two are tightly coupled.

[This Web Applications (StackExchange) Question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/50455/how-to-rename-a-github-wiki-page) has some alternatives you may consider, i.e. instead of renaming the page, create a copy. Then edit the original page so that it directs visitors to the new page via a link. This way the original page link remains valid but directs visitors to the new page.

Comment: At least I wasn't missing anything.  I am used to some MediaWiki handling all the logic behind the scenes.  Thanks!